# Combining line and scatters in Apexcharts

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I'm trying to use Apexcharts to render a combined chart with one line and one scatter series.

My problem is that the scatter points seem to disappear when I add the line series. If I remove the line series, the scatters are rendered correctly. What did I miss?

```
const options = {
  series: [{ "name": "Line",
        "type": "line",
        "data": [{
            "x": 1660081800000,
            "y": 2.8469434822183
        }, {
            "x": 1660082672727.2698,
            "y": 2.68695676198207
        }, {
            "x": 1660083545454.546,
            "y": 2.41073749840749
        }, {
            "x": 1660084418181.8162,
            "y": 2.10159299031736
        }, {
            "x": 1660085290909.0923,
            "y": 1.87225022750918
        }]
    },
    {
        "name": "Points",
        "type": "scatter",
        "data": [{
            "x": 1660081800000,
            "y": 0.016
        }, {
            "x": 1660082672727.2698,
            "y": 1.272
        }, {
            "x": 1660083545454.546,
            "y": 3.386
        }]
    }
 ],
  tooltip: {
    shared: false,
    intersect: true,
  },
  legend: {
    show: false
  },
  chart: {
    toolbar: { show: false }
  },
  xaxis: {
     type: 'datetime'
  },
  markers: {
    size: [6, 0]
  },
  fill: {
    type:'solid',
  },
  // fill: {
  //   type:'solid',
  // },
  yaxis: {
    labels: {
      formatter: (value) => value?.toFixed(0)
    }
  }
};

const chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ov24fwsy/

Answer (score 1):

The order of the series seems to matter - adding the scatter data first solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that you pass an array of marker sizes, first series that chart recieves has size 6, second one 0. **If scatter graph has marker of size 0, dots will not be visible.** Thats why changing order of series works for you. Try changing array to a single number.

```
  markers: {
    size: 6
  },
```